# topological sort using queue in a graph

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, graph-theory, depth-first-search

The below is my reading of a topological sort algorithm on a queue, written in my textbook:

```
void topologicalsort(struct Graph* G){
    struct queue* Q;
    int counter;
    int v,w;
    Q=createqueue();
    counter=0;
    for(v=0;v<G->V;v++){
       if(indegree[v]==0)
          enqueue(Q,v);
       while(!isemptyqueue(Q)){
          v=dequeue(Q);
          topologicalorder[v]=++counter;
          for each w to adjacent to v
             if(--indegree[w]==0){
             enqueue(Q,w);
             }


       }
    } 
}
```

The algorithm is failing for the following graph:

[image: graph the algorithm fails on]

If in the given graph initially 7 5 3 has in-degree zero then they will be inserted in the queue but for any of the vertices adjacent to `7 5 3` we are not having any vertex with degree 1. This implies that `if(--indegree[w]==0)` will not hold true for `7 5 3` hence there will be no further enqueuing inside the queue, and hence the algorithm will not process further vertices. **I'd like to know why is the algorithm failing if the graph is a DAG? In which way is it incorrect?**

I know that we can also implement topological sort using DFS, but I want to implement the below as-is:

[image: the pseudocode of the algorithm I want to implement]

Comment: Also, there are no trace of the definitions of `struct queue`, `struct Graph`, `createqueue()`, `dequeue()`, `enqueue()` and `indegree`...

Comment: Mr i am asking about the logic only not to find bug in my program @Ruks

Comment: Plus that code's not even valid... `for each w to ...`? If you're just using psuedocode, why is this tagged C?

Comment: The provided algorithm is C-like psuedo code, you need to implement it in whatever language you choose such as C.

Comment: LIsten all of you I am talking about the logic only for topological sort please If you find any error while tracing the algorithm please tell me the required changes

Comment: Punctuation is very important. It is also important to remember that we owe you nothing. Your tone seems to imply otherwise.

Comment: sorry for my language I don't know english i use google translate to write My mother tongue is hindi very sorry @MadPhysicist

Comment: Please begin by making the requested edits. Remove the images, update your code to provide a runs example with a clear problem statement. You can use the "edit" button underneath the question to do this.

Comment: Well i write every thing in very respect way i dont know how google translate it very badly again sorry for who are helping me

Comment: No worries. I'll do my best to work with the language barrier and rephrase if my comments are unclear.

Comment: @MadPhysicist See initially you for loop will going to insert `7 5 3` in the queue after that you will come to while loop an d till now you are having `7 5 3` inside queue now you will dequeue one by one from the queue and for the further enqueue THIS statement has to be executed `if(--indegree[w]==0)` for this to be executed we must have a vertex adjacent `7 or 5 or 3` with indegree `1` can you tell which vertex out of 11 8 10 that are adjacent to 7 5 3 have indegree 1 because i think indegree of them are 2

Comment: While this is a reasonable question, it is fundamentally just a typo - a simple transcription mistake when going from text into code. This would make the question off topic. Perhaps it should be left as-is, since the textbook it refers to is popular, and more than one person may be thrown off by it. **Please include the author and title of the textbook in the question itself, so that people would have easier time if they search for this problem.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm implementation is incorrect. Here `while(!isemptyqueue(Q))` isn't under the `for(v=0;v<G->V;v++)` (See the indentation in the algorithm). See below for more clarification:

```
void topologicalsort(struct Graph* G){
    struct queue* Q;
    int counter;
    int v,w;
    Q=createqueue();
    counter=0;
    for(v=0;v<G->V;v++){
       if(indegree[v]==0)
          enqueue(Q,v);
    }

    while(!isemptyqueue(Q)){
         v=dequeue(Q);
         topologicalorder[v]=++counter;
         for each w to adjacent to v {
             if(--indegree[w]==0){
                 enqueue(Q,w);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

This will work for every DAG.

Comment: In the book, they removed the trailing brackets for the `for`-loop and the OP mistook the curly bracket of the `while` loop with the `for`-loop... Thus, signifying one of the major importance of having curly brackets to start a code block...

Comment: @Ruks you are right. I have to face problem for that many times.

Comment: See initially  you for loop will going to insert `7 5 3` in the queue after that you will come to `while` loop an d till now you are having `7 5 3` inside queue now you will dequeue one by one from the queue and for the further enqueue THIS statement has to be executed `if(--indegree[w]==0)` for this to be executed we must have a vertex adjacent `7` or `5` or `3`  with indegree `1` can you tell which vertex out of `11 8 10` that are adjacent to `7 5 3`  have indegree 1 @nightfury1204

Comment: @newby i added curly braces does that clarify? And `if(--indegree[w]==0)` will be executed. Also `if(--indegree[w]==0)` means `--indegree[w];  if(indegree[w]==0))`

Comment: here indegree of 11 8 and 10 are 2 or 1 ? well thanks for helping I am from india @nightfury1204

Comment: After  applying this for loop for `for each w to adjacent to v { ` for `7 5 3`. indegree of `11 8 10` will be `0` and they will be in the `queue`.

Comment: but initially  the degree of 11 8 and 10 are zero then how are they becoming zero on  --indegree[w]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183280/discussion-between-nightfury1204-and-newby).